# Problemas Para Rodar o Angular Localhost

Tags: angular

Não consigo linkar o Angular no meu projeto .

Essa é minha Estrutura :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Baixei o Angular via Bower e pra linkar ele usei o seguinte Script nas minhas Views
src="../../../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"script>

Mas quando vou fazer um simples teste do tipo :

{{teste}}

O navegador retorna

GET http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED

Alguém me ajuda por favor

Comment: Amigo, acredito que esteja faltando alguns arquivos de configuração

Comment: Sabe me dizer quais ? Ou algum lugar em que consigo achar essa solução ? Por Favor

Comment: O que posso te sugerir é criar um app de exemplo, o que todo tutorial vai te mostrar, `ng new <nome-projeto>` e observa a estrutura, provavelmente seu projeto q vc baixou esta faltando algo para gerar este erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provavelmente não está encontrando o arquivo por conta da configuração que foi feita para o localhost (por exemplo, colocar o server pra apontar para pasta src e linkar diretamente um arquivo no código para uma pasta superior). Adiciona o script via cdn como no exemplo abaixo, se funcionar então é isso. Mas se quiser usar o angular num projeto [é melhor gerar um app](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) pois vem tudo configurado.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <p>1 + 1 é igual a {{ 1 + 1 }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Deneeese Muito Obrigado